# How to read 10 records each time from csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I want to read a csv file which having 1000 rows so, I decide to read this file in chunks. But I'm facing issues while reading this csv file.

I want to read first 10 records at 1st iteration and convert its specific columns to the python dictionary at 2nd iteration skip first 10 records and read next 10 records like that.

**Input.csv-**

```
time,line_id,high,low,avg,total,split_counts
1468332421098000,206,50879,50879,50879,2,"[50000,2]"
1468332421195000,206,39556,39556,39556,2,"[30000,2]"
1468332421383000,206,61636,61636,61636,2,"[60000,2]"
1468332423568000,206,47315,38931,43123,4,"[30000,2][40000,2]"
1468332423489000,206,38514,38445,38475,6,"[30000,6]"
1468332421672000,206,60079,60079,60079,2,"[60000,2]"
1468332421818000,206,44664,44664,44664,2,"[40000,2]"
1468332422164000,206,48500,48500,48500,2,"[40000,2]"
1468332423490000,206,39469,37894,38206,12,"[30000,12]"
1468332422538000,206,44023,44023,44023,2,"[40000,2]"
1468332423491000,206,38813,38813,38813,2,"[30000,2]"
1468332423528000,206,75970,75970,75970,2,"[70000,2]"
1468332423533000,206,42546,42470,42508,4,"[40000,4]"
1468332423536000,206,41065,40888,40976,4,"[40000,4]"
1468332423566000,206,66401,62453,64549,6,"[60000,6]"
```

**Program Code-**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   s = 0
   while(True):
      n = 10
      df = pandas.read_csv('Input.csv', skiprows=s, nrows=n)
      d = dict(zip(df.time, df.split_counts))
      print d
      s += n
```

**I'm facing this Issue-**

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'
```

I know in the 2nd iteration It unable to identify time and split_counts attributes But Is there any way do what I want?

Comment: you can also use the chunksize argument of read_csv. That'll mean this is O(n) rather that O(n^2) because you would only read the file once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first iteration should work fine, but any further iterations are problematic.

`read_csv` has an `headers` kwarg with default value `infer` (which is basically `0`). This means that the first row in the parsed csv will be used as the columns' names in the dataframe.

The `read_csv` also has another kwarg, `names`.

As explained in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> header : int or list of ints, default ‘infer’
>   Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is as if set to 0 if no names passed, otherwise None. Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names. The header can be a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be skipped (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.
>
> names : array-like, default None
>   List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None

You should pass `headers=None` and `names=['time', 'line_id', 'high', 'low', 'avg', 'total', 'split_counts']` to `read_csv`.

Comment: Yes, I try this solution, but there is problem with `while(True)`, I get error in last iteration : `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: @jezrael- yes for that we need to take care it will return empty dataframe.

Comment: @DeepSpace- Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rather `chunksize` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''time,line_id,high,low,avg,total,split_counts
1468332421098000,206,50879,50879,50879,2,"[50000,2]"
1468332421195000,206,39556,39556,39556,2,"[30000,2]"
1468332421383000,206,61636,61636,61636,2,"[60000,2]"
1468332423568000,206,47315,38931,43123,4,"[30000,2][40000,2]"
1468332423489000,206,38514,38445,38475,6,"[30000,6]"
1468332421672000,206,60079,60079,60079,2,"[60000,2]"
1468332421818000,206,44664,44664,44664,2,"[40000,2]"
1468332422164000,206,48500,48500,48500,2,"[40000,2]"
1468332423490000,206,39469,37894,38206,12,"[30000,12]"
1468332422538000,206,44023,44023,44023,2,"[40000,2]"
1468332423491000,206,38813,38813,38813,2,"[30000,2]"
1468332423528000,206,75970,75970,75970,2,"[70000,2]"
1468332423533000,206,42546,42470,42508,4,"[40000,4]"
1468332423536000,206,41065,40888,40976,4,"[40000,4]"
1468332423566000,206,66401,62453,64549,6,"[60000,6]"'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename

#for testing 2
reader = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), chunksize=2)
print (reader)
<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x000000000AD1CD68>
```

```
for df in reader:
    print(dict(zip(df.time, df.split_counts)))

{1468332421098000: '[50000,2]', 1468332421195000: '[30000,2]'}
{1468332421383000: '[60000,2]', 1468332423568000: '[30000,2][40000,2]'}
{1468332423489000: '[30000,6]', 1468332421672000: '[60000,2]'}
{1468332421818000: '[40000,2]', 1468332422164000: '[40000,2]'}
{1468332423490000: '[30000,12]', 1468332422538000: '[40000,2]'}
{1468332423491000: '[30000,2]', 1468332423528000: '[70000,2]'}
{1468332423533000: '[40000,4]', 1468332423536000: '[40000,4]'}
{1468332423566000: '[60000,6]'}
```

See [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).

Comment: @jezrael- Thank you for good response. This is also good way to do what I want.